# Weird matrix identity

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I stumbled upon a weird equality that I can't seem to explain:

For a $N\times N$ (symmetric) matrix $\mathbf{X}$ that satisfies the eigenvalue problem

$$\mathbf{X} \mathbf{v}_k = \lambda_k \mathbf{v}_k$$

and a $N\times1$ matrix $\mathbf{u}$ that is split in 2 (elements in the first half are equal to 1, equal to -1 for the second half), i.e.

$$\mathbf{u}^T := \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\bigl[\underbrace{1 ...\ 1}_{\times N/2}\ \underbrace{-1\ ....-1}_{\times N/2}\bigr]$$

the following (apparantly) holds

$$ \mathbf{u}^T(z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{u} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{(\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v}_k)^2}{z-\lambda_k}.$$

$z$ is complex but vanishingly close to the real axis.

---

I'm guessing it has something to do with the resolvent

$$ (z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X})^{-1} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\mathbf{X}^k}{z^{k+1}}$$

but I can't figure it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an unstated assumption that $v_k$ are ortho-normal (ortho is ensured if the matrix has distinct eigenvalues). One can always choose $v_k$ so they are ortho-normal.

That said, we can write $u$ as
$$ 
u = \sum_1^k \sigma_k v_k
$$
where $$ \sigma_k = u^T v_k$$

Hence
$$ \begin{align} u^T (z I - A)^{-1} u &= u^T\sum_1^k \sigma_k(z I - A)^{-1} v_k \\
&=  \sum_1^k \sigma_k \frac{1}{z-\lambda_k} u^T v_k \\
&=  \sum_1^k  \frac{\left(u^T v_k\right)^2 }{z-\lambda_k} \\
\end{align}
$$
The above result is true for *any* real vector $u$.

Comment: Nice succint answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think the identity

$\mathbf{u}^T(z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{u} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{(\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v}_k)^2}{z-\lambda_k} \tag{1}$

holds for *any* $\mathbf u$, provided we take the $\mathbf v_k$ to be normalized to unity, which always a possible choice in the present context.  The matrix $\mathbf X$, being symmetric, is possessed of an *orthonormal* eigenbasis $\mathbf v_k$, and we can expand $\mathbf u$ in this basis, to wit:

$\mathbf u = \sum_1^N (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k) \mathbf v_k; \tag{2}$

now observe that $z$, being complex, satisfies $z \ne \lambda_k$ for all $k$, $1 \le k \le N$, whence $1 /(z - \lambda_k)$ is well-defined.  This being the case, we have, for each $\mathbf v_k$,

$(z - \mathbf X) \mathbf v_k = (z - \lambda_k) \mathbf v_k, \tag{3}$

which immediately leads to

$\mathbf v_k = (1 / (z - \lambda_k)) (z - \mathbf X)\mathbf v_k.  \tag{4}$

Substituting (4) into (2) yields

$\mathbf u = \sum_1^N (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k) (1 / (z - \lambda_k)) (z - \mathbf X)\mathbf v_k = (z - \mathbf X) \sum_1^N (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k)(1 / (z - \lambda_k)) \mathbf v_k, \tag{5}$

and since $z - \mathbf X$ is nonsingular by virtue of the fact that $z$ cannot be a (real) eigenvalue of $X$, we may write

$(z - \mathbf X)^{-1} \mathbf u = \sum_1^N (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k)(1 / (z - \lambda_k)) \mathbf v_k; \tag{6}$

taking the product of each side with $\mathbf u^T$ now gives

$\mathbf u^T (z - \mathbf X)^{-1} \mathbf u = \sum_1^N (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k)(1 / (z - \lambda_k)) (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k) =  \sum_1^N (1 / (z - \lambda_k)) (\mathbf u^T \mathbf v_k)^2, \tag{7}$

the desired result.

Note that if the $\mathbf v_k$ are *not* normalized, (2) would fail, and the ensuing equations would (presumably) have to be modified.

Hope this helps.  Holiday Greetings,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Very nice answer Robert. Thank you, and Happy Holiday to you!